# ClassCastException whlile accessing custom object in Geode's Function.execute() method

Tags: geode

I am adding the custom object(Account) into Cache and then trying to access the object in the Function.execute() method.

But it throws `org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.PdxInstanceImpl cannot be cast to com.sas.cpm.model.Account`.

**Custom object Account.java**

```
public class Account implements PdxSerializable, Declarable{

public Account() {
          super();
          // TODO Auto-generated constructor
     }

@Override
       public void fromData(PdxReader pr) {…..}

@Override
       public void toData(PdxWriter pw) {… }
}
```

**Client code:**

```
ClientCache cache = new ClientCacheFactory()
            .addPoolLocator("localhost", 10334).set("log-level", "INFO").create();

    // create a local region that matches the server region
// Account is the domain object 
    Region<String, Account> region =
        cache.<String, Account>createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY)
            .create("testRegion");

feedData(region);   //add Account object to region
Execution execution = FunctionService.onRegion(region);
ResultCollector<Integer, List> rc = execution.execute("UpdateCost");//.ID);//com.sas.cpm.geode
```

**Function class : UpdateCost.java**

```
public class UpdateCost implements Function{
   @Override
            public void execute(FunctionContext context) {

                 RegionFunctionContext regionContext = (RegionFunctionContext) context;
                 Region<String, Account> region = regionContext.getDataSet();
                for ( Map.Entry<String, Account> entry : region.entrySet() ) {
                        Account account = entry.getValue();                   /// THIS LINE GIVES THE ERROR
                }

        }

 }
```

**Error:**

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.geode.cache.execute.FunctionException: org.apache.geode.cache.client.ServerOperationException: remote server on dsinsbb01ina4(46560:loner):59343:2f7e3885: While performing a remote executeRegionFunction
>       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.execute.ServerRegionFunctionExecutor.executeOnServer(ServerRegionFunctionExecutor.java:229)
>       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.execute.ServerRegionFunctionExecutor.executeFunction(ServerRegionFunctionExecutor.java:178)
>       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.execute.ServerRegionFunctionExecutor.execute(ServerRegionFunctionExecutor.java:379)
>       at geodeproject1.Example.funcUpdateExec(Example.java:186)
>       at geodeproject1.Example.main(Example.java:68)
>   Caused by: org.apache.geode.cache.client.ServerOperationException: remote server on dsinsbb01ina4(46560:loner):59343:2f7e3885: While performing a remote executeRegionFunction
>       at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.ExecuteRegionFunctionOp$ExecuteRegionFunctionOpImpl.processResponse(ExecuteRegionFunctionOp.java:606)
>       at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.AbstractOp.processResponse(AbstractOp.java:225)
>       at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.AbstractOp.attemptReadResponse(AbstractOp.java:198)
>       at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.AbstractOp.attempt(AbstractOp.java:386)
>       at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.ConnectionImpl.execute(ConnectionImpl.java:269)
>       at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.pooling.PooledConnection.execute(PooledConnection.java:325)
>       at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.executeWithPossibleReAuthentication(OpExecutorImpl.java:892)
>       at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.execute(OpExecutorImpl.java:171)
>       at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.PoolImpl.execute(PoolImpl.java:772)
>       at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.ExecuteRegionFunctionOp.execute(ExecuteRegionFunctionOp.java:162)
>       at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.ServerRegionProxy.executeFunction(ServerRegionProxy.java:732)
>       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.execute.ServerRegionFunctionExecutor.executeOnServer(ServerRegionFunctionExecutor.java:220)
>       ... 4 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.geode.cache.execute.FunctionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.PdxInstanceImpl cannot be cast to com.sas.cpm.model.Account
>       at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.ExecuteRegionFunctionOp$ExecuteRegionFunctionOpImpl.processResponse(ExecuteRegionFunctionOp.java:583)
>       ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.PdxInstanceImpl cannot be cast to com.sas.cpm.model.Account
>       at com.sas.cpm.geode.UpdateCost.execute(UpdateCost.java:49)
>       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.execute.AbstractExecution.executeFunctionLocally(AbstractExecution.java:331)
>       at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.execute.AbstractExecution$2.run(AbstractExecution.java:300)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.ClusterDistributionManager.runUntilShutdown(ClusterDistributionManager.java:949)
>       at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.ClusterDistributionManager.doFunctionExecutionThread(ClusterDistributionManager.java:803)
>       at org.apache.geode.internal.logging.LoggingThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(LoggingThreadFactory.java:121)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

The `ClassCastException` is thrown because you're receiving a `PdxInstance` from the cache instead of an `Account`, this happens when you implement the `PdxSerializable` interface in your domain object and configure PDX Serialization with `read-serialized=true`.

Please have a look at [Implementing PdxSerializable in Your Domain Object](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/geode/developing/data_serialization/use_pdx_serializable.html) and [Programming Your Application to Use PdxInstances](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/geode/developing/data_serialization/program_application_for_pdx.html) for further details. 
Cheers.